# How do I restrict to open the js file contents in browser/postman

Tags: node.js, api, security, authentication, restriction

I am trying to restrict the code server js files to open in browser directly.
Like:

```
http:<<domain>>:<<port>>/<<server.js>>
```

If I hit this url in browser the code displays as is in js file and everyone can see the js contents and all the routing and configuration. If If I will put below code in main server js file it restrict me to use the api's for front end.

```
app.get('/server.js', function(req, res, next) {
res.json({
    auth: false
});  });
```

Please help me to restrict the code to view in postman or browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in adding below small script in main server.js(might be app.js/node.js in your file structure) file

```
app.all(['*server.js*', '*Config/**', '*Models/**', '*package.json*', '*bower.json*', '*README.md*', '*Public/**'], function (req, res, next){
    res.send({ auth: false });
});
```

Thank you once again [nmnsud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5692251/nmnsud)